# WordPress Contact 7 Form - Remove WordPress from the From Sections

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I want to remove the WordPress tag from the From section in when using the contact 7 plugin on WordPress. How can i do this?

[image: wordpress email from tag]

See below for the settings I use for the Contact 7 Plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> change contact form setting as shown in below screens
>   [image: contact from setting]

Comment: SOLVED! Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0):

> Read this below article. Hope it will help you.

https://contactform7.com/faq/mail-that-comes-through-the-contact-form-shows-wordpress-as-its-sender-name/

Comment: Thanks. This Information is helpful :)